# firstName lastName to lastName, firstName in Excel spreadsheet

Tags: regex, excel, formula

I am trying to get an excel spreadsheet that has the names Jane Doe and John Smith, go from that to Doe, Jane, and Smith, John.

I can only find ways to go from lastName, firstName to firstName lastName, but none for the contrary.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For formulas use:

```
=MID(A1,FIND(" ",A1)+1,999) & ", " & LEFT(A1,FIND(" ",A1)-1)
```

[image]

Now to the next question:  What if there are more than just the first and last name?

Use this:

```
=MID(A1,FIND("}}}",SUBSTITUTE(A1," ","}}}",LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1," ",""))))+1,999) & ", " & LEFT(A1,FIND("}}}",SUBSTITUTE(A1," ","}}}",LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1," ",""))))-1)
```

It will assume the last word is the last name.

[image: ![enter image description here]

Answer (score 2):

Select only the cells you wish to convert and run this small macro:

```
Sub NameFixer()
   For Each r In Selection
      ary = Split(r.Value, " ")
      r.Value = ary(1) & ", " & ary(0)
   Next r
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternate formula solution:

```
=LEFT(TRIM(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(A1," ",REPT(" ",99)),99))&", "&A1,LEN(A1)+1)
```