# changing column data with "lastname, firstname" to "firstname lastname" in python pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, split, reverse

I have python pandas dataframe, served up by power bi data source transformation support for execution of python script, where one of the columns consists of `lastname, firstname` and I need it to consist of `firstname lastname`.

I've tried the following split, reversed, join approach which works on a standalone string argument but generates `AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'split'` when I try it on column data in a pandas dataframe.

```
name = 'LastName, FirstName'
' '.join(reversed(name.split(', ')))
# output = 'FirstName LastName'

import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'full_name': ['doe, john', 'smith, kate', 'jones, susan', 'edwards, jack' ],
                   'num_legs': [2, 4, 8, 0],
                   'num_wings': [2, 0, 0, 0],
                   'num_specimen_seen': [10, 2, 1, 8]},
                   index=['falcon', 'dog', 'spider', 'fish'])
df
df['full_name'] = ' '.join(reversed(df['full_name'].split(', ')))
# output = AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'split'
```

Searching SO i see hits for doing this something of this nature in an [excel column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35092908/firstname-lastname-to-lastname-firstname-in-excel-spreadsheet) and in a [R list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53672694/changing-firstname-lastname-to-lastname-firstname) but nothing i have been able to find yet for column in a python pandas dataframe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your case we can do `split` with `map` PS : `::-1` here is reversed the order

```
df.full_name=df.full_name.str.split(', ').map(lambda x : ' '.join(x[::-1]))
df.full_name
falcon        john doe
dog         kate smith
spider     susan jones
fish      jack edwards
Name: full_name, dtype: object
```

Comment: i thought my solution would be faster ... but profiling it on 50k entries this solution took 2 seconds, mine was 3.4 (to run 10 times with timeit)

Answer (score 3):

A combination of pandas' string methods could help here : for speed, I would suggest running a list comprehension within python itself. The string methods in Pandas are provided primarily for convenience/simplicity.

```
df['full_name'] = df.full_name.str.split(",").str[::-1].str.join(",")


          full_name     num_legs    num_wings   num_specimen_seen
falcon     john,doe         2           2             10
dog        kate,smith       4           0             2
spider     susan,jones      8           0             1
fish       jack,edwards     0           0             8
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is because the variable's type `type(df['full_name'])` is `<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>`. Convert it to list and then operate:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'full_name': ['doe, john', 'smith, kate', 'jones, susan', 'edwards, jack' ],
        'num_legs': [2, 4, 8, 0],
        'num_wings': [2, 0, 0, 0],
        'num_specimen_seen': [10, 2, 1, 8]},
        index=['falcon', 'dog', 'spider', 'fish'])

print(map(lambda x: x.split(',')[::-1], df['full_name'].tolist()))
```

Comment: thanks for the response, when i run this i get `<map object at 0x000001E66DE60710>` for output and the output of executing `df.full_name` after that appears unchanged